# Android ProgressDialog não aparece

Tags: android, dialog, asynctask

Estou tentando mostrar um ProgressDialog no processo de download de um ficheiro binário, contudo este não aparece, e não obtenho qualquer erro também.
Resumidamente explicarei a maneira como tenho o código estruturado

Na minha MainActivity defino um botão para obter esse ficheiro... Ao clicarmos no botão cujo nome é botao_getbscan, aparece-nos um AlertDialog, com uma série de parâmetros para o utilizador definir, de forma a construir uma string que representa o URL para fazer o download do ficheiro binário. Após a definição desses parâmetros o utilizador carrega no botão ok do AlertDialog e este desaparece, começando a fazer o download, como podem ver de seguida:

```
botao_getbscan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
botao_getbscan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Se houver internet avança...
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                // Construção de um dialog para introduzir os valores de contrução do b-scan
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                View dialog_view = li.inflate(R.layout.getbscan_dialog,null);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialog_view);

                // Define o titulo e a mensagem do dialog
                //(...)

                // Define os botões do dialog
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                       //Definição de uma série de parâmetros para construir uma string com o "GET" pretendido...
                                       final String fullstring = "http://...................................;

                                       // Inicia o download e armazena na memória interna...
                                       boolean succed = StartDownload(fullstring);

                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                // Cria e mostra o alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            else {
                AlertDialog.Builder saveDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                saveDialog.setTitle("No Internet Connection Detected");
                saveDialog.setMessage("A connection to the internet is required to retrieve B-Scan. Please check your connection settings and try again.");
                saveDialog.setNeutralButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                saveDialog.show();
            }
        }
    });//End of Get B-Scan Button
```

O método StartDownload consiste no seguinte:

```
public boolean StartDownload(String string){
    BitmapDownloaderTask object = new BitmapDownloaderTask(MainActivity.this);
    object.execute(string);
    try {
        byteArray = object.get();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
} // End of StartDownload
```

Em seguida tenho a minha AsyncTask num ficheiro diferente ao qual chamei BitmapDownloaderTask.java, que basicamente define a minha classe BitmapDownloaderTask que estende uma AsyncTask. É aqui que defino o progress dialog, que gostaria que aparece-se após clicar no botão OK do meu AlertDialog, visto que após isso inicia-se de imediato o processo de Download.. Contudo o progress dialog não aparece e também não obtenho qualquer erro. Tenho então o seguinte:

```
class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, byte[]> {

private ProgressDialog dialog;
private Context context;
private byte[] byteArray;

//--------------------CONSTRUCTOR--------------------------------//
public BitmapDownloaderTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.byteArray = null;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
}

//--------------PRE EXECUTE--------------------------------------//
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.show();
}


//--------------BACKGROUND---------------------------------------//
@Override
// Actual download method, run in the task thread
protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {

    // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
    return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
}


//--------------POST EXECUTE-------------------------------------//
@Override
// Once the image is downloaded
protected void onPostExecute(byte[] byteArray) {
    super.onPostExecute(byteArray);
    dialog.dismiss();
    if(byteArray != null){
        //pDialog.dismiss();
    }else{
        //pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this.context,"B-scan doens't exist, or there was a connection problem!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

static byte[] downloadBitmap(String url) {
// ......................
}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Você implementou algo no método `downloadBitmap()`?

Comment: @ramaral Sim implementei, é um simples metodo de download a partir de um url utilizando HttpEntity HttpResponse e InputStream...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A razão de isso acontecer deve-se à chamado do método [get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) da classe *AsyncTask* no método `StartDownload()`.

```
public boolean StartDownload(String string){
    BitmapDownloaderTask object = new BitmapDownloaderTask(MainActivity.this);
    object.execute(string);
    try {
        byteArray = object.get();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
} // End of StartDownload
```

Esse método bloqueia a *UIThread* enquanto o *AsyncTask* é executado.

O método `dialog.show();` é chamado no `onPreExecute()` mas como a *UIThread* está bloqueada o *Dialog* não pode ser apresentado.

Na altura em que a *UIThread* é desbloqueada, já o método `onPosExecute()` foi chamado e a linha `dialog.dismiss()` executada.

Não faz sentido usar uma *AsyncTask* e depois ficar *à espera* que ela termine dentro da *UIThread*.

Tire a chamada ao método `get()` e faça o tratamento do resultado do *Download* dentro do método `onPostExecute();` ou, dentro dele, chame um método da *Activity* que o faça.

**Implementação da *BitmapDownloaderTask*.**

Como *BitmapDownloaderTask* reside num ficheiro próprio, teremos que passar, no construtor, a classe que contém o método que irá tratar o resultado.

Para que ela possa ser usada com qualquer *Activity* além da *MainActivity*, declaramos uma interface que deverá ser implementada por ela(Activity).

```
class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, byte[]> {

    // Interface a ser implementada pela classe consumidora
    public interface OnDownloadFinishedListener{
        public void onDownloadFinished(byte[] resultado);
    }

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Context context;
    private OnDownloadFinishedListener listener;
    private byte[] byteArray;

    //--------------------CONSTRUCTOR--------------------------------//
    public BitmapDownloaderTask(Activity activity) {

        this.context = activity;

        //Verifica se a Activity passada implementa a interface
        if(activity instanceof OnDownloadFinishedListener){
            this.listener = (OnDownloadFinishedListener)activity;
        }
        else{
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                      + " must implement OnDownloadFinishedListener");
        }
        this.byteArray = null;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    //--------------PRE EXECUTE--------------------------------------//
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.show();
    }


    //--------------BACKGROUND---------------------------------------//
    @Override
    // Actual download method, run in the task thread
    protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    }


    //--------------POST EXECUTE-------------------------------------//
    @Override
    // Once the image is downloaded
    protected void onPostExecute(byte[] byteArray) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        //Se houver um resultado
        //Chammos o método da interface(Activity)
        if(byteArray != null){
            listener.onDownloadFinished(byteArray);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this.context,"B-scan doens't exist, or there was a connection problem!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    static byte[] downloadBitmap(String url) {
        // ......................
    }
}
```

Faça a MainActivity implementar a interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnDownloadFinishedListener{

    ..........
    ..........
    ..........
    ..........
    @Override
    public void onDownloadFinished(byte[] resultado) {

        //Faça aqui o tratamento do resultado
    }
}
```

O método `StartDownload()` será assim:

```
public void StartDownload(String string){
    BitmapDownloaderTask object = new BitmapDownloaderTask(this);
    object.execute(string);

} // End of StartDownload
```

<sub>**Nota:** O método passa a retornar nada</sub>

Comment: Eu percebi o que você disse, mas o método StartDownload apenas chama a AsyncTask, e depois com o object.get() eu obtenho o array de bytes que representa o resultado do download efectuado na async task... nao vejo como fazer isso de outra maneira... eu preciso desse array de bytes na minha MainActivity...  poderia explicar-me como fazer isso no onPostExecute()?

Comment: A classe *BitmapDownloaderTask* é declarada na *Activity* ou está num ficheiro próprio?

Comment: está num ficheiro próprio... ficheiro esse que contem a classe BitmapDownloaderTask que extende a AsyncTask, e contém ainda o método  static byte[] downloadBitmap(String url) que é responsável por efectuar o download do array de bytes. Obrigado!

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Consegui implementar a tua solução, grande ajuda mesmo :D

Answer (score 0):

Seu código está certo, verifique se ele esta passando por esse trecho:

```
    //--------------PRE EXECUTE--------------------------------------//
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();

       dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
       dialog.show();
    }
```

Se não estiver passando, ele será executado em background por isso você não consegue ver o load, uma alternativa é você colocar seu Progress Dialog dentro apenas do onClick.

Comment: Se o `dialog.show();`for colocado no `onClick()` onde se coloca o `dialog.dismiss();`?

Comment: @Leonardo Rocha em concreto como como colocava o dialog.show no onClick? criava o objecto na minha MainActivity? é que tenho a asynctask noutro ficheiro e não no ficheiro do onClick que é o da classe MainActivity.  Seria algo como antes de botao_getbscan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() criava o objecto to tipo progressdialog e depois dentro do onClick colocaria dialog.show()? e onde ficaria o dialog.dismiss(), como disse o ramaral... Obrigado!

Comment: @Leonardo Rocha Esqueci-me de referir que o programa passa em onPreExecute(), verifiquei através de Logs e fazendo debug...

Comment: Você deve criar p objeto do tipo progressdialog e dentro do onClick colocar o dialog.show(), o dialog,dismiss ficaria no preExecute.